# Capture a point cloud at a specific frame from the geometry nodes simulation zone

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I have a point cloud which is the the result of several iterations in the simulation zone of the geometry nodes.

[image]

Now, I would like to capture this specific frame of the simulation e.g. to use it as a starting configuration for another simulation.
Is there an elegant way to copy the point cloud from a given frame?

I tried to apply the geometry nodes modifier, however that only seems to work for mesh data, not for a point cloud.
I can use the "points to vertices" node to convert it into a mesh before applying, however once I convert it back to points the radius information is lost. I guess I could copy the radius to a named attribute to restore it, but isn't there some more elegant way?